# Should I clean-up handlePress variables in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react native and something is really confusing to me. What type of objects should I cleanup before the component unMount? I know I should clean all the API calls, what else?? Let's say I have a button like this

```
 const _renderTruncatedFooter = (handlePress) => {
    return (
      <Text
        onPress={handlePress}>
        Read more
      </Text>
    );
  };
```

Should I cleanup buttons in useEffect return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't clean up any objects. You only clean up side effects like API calls, event listeners, timers, etc.

Objects and functions will be cleaned up by [garbage collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#garbage_collection).

Comment: Even if this function submits data  to the database?

Comment: Whether you want to cancel that depends on whether it makes sense to cancel updates when component unmounts - which often doesn't make sense. If I updated my profile and saved it, it wouldn't make sense to cancel it if I go back quickly. But also, you're talking about cleaning up the API request, not the function itself.